# Set up unit testing with Mocha on an AngularJs app

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, karma-runner

I'm trying to setup unit testing on my webapp using mocha. My webapp uses AngularJs and since I'm still new to this framework, I'm having a hard time to setup this.

In fact, is there a way to setup this by using nothing else than mocha? I mean, is it possible to setup my unit tests without Karma or any other test runners (and no browser)?

Here's my code to test :

```
define(['angular'], function (angular) {
var module = angular.module('MyModule', []);

module.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window) {
        $scope.test = function () {
            $window.alert('Not implemented yet.');
        };
    }]);

    return module;
});
```

And here's my test code:

```
require("chai");
require('../lib/angular/angular-mocks');

describe("Unit testing example", function() {

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('MyModule'));

    it('should test nothing', function() {
        expect(true).to.be.true;
    })

});
```

When I try to execute this, I receive this error:

```
angular.mock = {};
^
ReferenceError: angular is not defined
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately, I pretty sure I will need to setup karma or another test runner to make this works cause without doing this (or run it through a browser), the DOM will not exists and it's required.

Correct me if this is wrong ;)

Comment: I did not address that in my answer but your ``beforeEach`` looks suspicious. ``beforeEach`` takes a function as parameter. Does angular.mock.module('MyModule') return a function? One that ``beforeEach`` can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need something that will provide some sort of browser environment for your Angular code. There are multiple options:

- [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom).
- Headless solutions like PhantomJS.
- Actual browsers.

Each of these solutions provide a browser environment which is progressively closer to the "real thing".

What you need exactly depends on:

- That minimum AngularJS requires. I don't use AngularJS so I don't know what this minimum is.
- What minimum *your* own code requires.

For instance, I've used jsdom for unit tests for code that just navigates up and down the DOM tree. Jsdom was perfect for this. However, when I tried to use jsdom to test code that uses [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), that did not work because jsdom does not provide this API. I've had to use real browsers to perform these tests.

A word of caution: if you care at all about cross-browser compatibility *nothing* replaces testing code against actual browsers. Just yesterday I diagnosed a problem that happened *only* in Safari. There was no way to catch this problem using anything else than Safari to test the offending code.

Comment: I finally come to this solution : Grunt, karma and phantomJs. Playing with jsDom and AngularJs was not a good idea in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For those facing this issue with jsdom for testing

Adding the following solve it for me seach for a day

```
require('mutationobserver-shim')
global.MutationObserver = global.window.MutationObserver
```

of course you need to npm yarn install mutationobserver-shim

Hope this helps